# How can I check if I'm at the category overview page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I check, if I'm at the overview page of all categories in WooCommerce? I've tried this function here but it don't works:

```
/**
 * Function to check if it's category overview page
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_category_overview() {
    $cat      = get_query_var( 'product_cat' );

    $category = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat, 'product_cat' );


    return ! empty( $category ) && $category->parent !== 0;
}
```

So I mean the page where I can see all categories and when I click on a category I'm getting redirected to all products in WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as,

```
function check_category_overview(){
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $children = get_terms( $queried_object->taxonomy, array(
        'parent'    => $queried_object->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );

    if($children) { // check if has subcategories
        // term has children

    }
    if($queried_object->parent){
        //check if has a parent category

    }

    if($queried_object->count){
        //check if has products in this category

    }
}
```

I have mentioned 3 conditions in this code, You can use appropriate one suitable for your requirement